# If $XYZ$ is a right scalene triangle and if one of its constituent triangles is equilateral, then the other triangle must be isosceles.

Tags: geometry

This question is related to a component of a proof I constructed. I have posted the (pending) proof for verification on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067151/use-the-information-given-to-construct-a-proof.

However, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could verify whether this specific statement I made is true:

> If $XYZ$ is a right scalene triangle and if one of its constituent
>   triangles is equilateral, then the other triangle must be isosceles
>   (and vice-versa).

In the above proof, this statement was made to justify the following key question and abstract answer:

> How can I show that a right scalene triangle consists of an
>   equilateral triangle and an isosceles triangle?
>
> Show that one of the triangles is an equilateral triangle.

In the above question, I also included the following diagram to illustrate the triangles:

[image]

Notice that the right scalene triangle consists of two other triangles when divided.

If anything is unclear, you may find clarification in the proof question posted above. Also, I will be glad to answer any questions if you'd prefer to ask me directly.

If my reasoning is incorrect, please explain why.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $W$ here\?

Comment: @Qwerty $W$ is the midpoint of the hypotenuse.

Comment: What does bring the adjective "scalene" in the title ? Do you mean by this "any right triangle" ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Use the information given to construct a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067151/use-the-information-given-to-construct-a-proof). While I appreciate that the original question was referenced, yet I don't see what the new question is here.

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean a right triangle that has no equal sides.

Comment: @dxiv I said in the question that this is a component of a proof I constructed.

Comment: @ThePointer In any right triangle the midpoint of the hypothenuse is the center of the circumscribed circle, so $WX = WY \implies WX = WY=WZ$. This was addressed in the original question and answer.

Comment: @dxiv I see. So my reasoning must be correct then?

Comment: You didn't really include any reasoning in this posted question. `if one of its constituent triangles is equilateral, then the other triangle must be isosceles (and vice-versa)` The `vice-versa` part is obviously false, take an isosceles right triangle for example.

Comment: @dxiv How so? If we have a right scalene triangle that consists of two triangles, one of which is isosceles, then must the other constituent triangle not be equilateral?

Comment: @ThePointer Seriously, did you take the time to draw an isosceles right triangle, as I just suggested in the previous comment, and *see* why the reverse implication is obviously false?

Comment: @dxiv I think the language I used might be the issue here. I didn't mean triangles within an equilateral or an isosceles; I meant if we have a right-scalene triangle and we are told that either (1) one of two triangles is an equilateral, or (2) one of the two triangles is an isosceles, but not both. In both situations the triangles would be drawn within a right scalene triangle.

Comment: @ThePointer Since both triangles share one angle with the right triangle, either can be equilateral if and only if the right triangle has an angle of $60^\circ$. Meanwhile, *any* right triangle is partitioned into two isosceles triangles by the midpoint of the hypothenuse. So I don't see the point being made, and if it's a matter of language or formulation I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question.  If the constituent triange is equilateral then one of the angels of the right triangle is 60.  And the other is 30.  Removing the equilateral triangle you'll be left with a triangle with the 30 degree angle and the 90 degree angle less 60 degrees.  As two of the angles are both 30, it is isoceles.

You second question is clearly false as only 60-30-90 triangles will have this property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which second question are you referring to? This is only the context of the 60-30-90 triangle.

Comment: "How can I show that a right scale ne triangle does...?"  That second question.  It isn't true that right scales have this property.  60-30-90s are the only ones that do.  So the property is false in general.

Comment: Ahh, you're correct. In that case, this error invalidates my proof, since it assumes the hypothesis true in constructing the conclusion. Thank you for the assistance.